# Access Variable from the same Class but different method - Android Eclipse - App

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, variables

I face an problem where I cannot access the `directory` variable from the `main` Method in eclipse. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity {

    public void main(String [] args) {

        Button Import = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ImportContactButton);

        Uri SDLocation = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        String path = "/Scanner/Data/";
        File directory = new File(SDLocation + path);
    }

    protected void CameraActivity() {

        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(directory);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
        intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );
        startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );

    }
}
```

I'm not sure wether it could because I'm using the wrong access modifiers on the classes, or the right access control modifiers on the classes. I tried many methods to access the variable but none are working, what am I doing wrong??? Help is much appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: Why have you written a main method?

Comment: And what `distance` variable you are talking about? I don't see it in your code...

Comment: @Dalija Prasnikar, Oh sorry, just corrected its the directory variable and @ Green goblin I thought it was nessecary to do so or is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are out of scope, directory is only valid until the end of the method 'main'. You should make it a class variable.

Also, a main method on an Android project is pretty useless (unless test purposes). So your code will not run as an Application, and can only run on console as a Java application.